# Eigenvalue distribution of random matrices

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, eigenvalues

Given basis $M_1,M_2\dotsc,M_{d^2}$ in $\mathbb C^{d\times d}$, we consider
$$\sum_i x_i M_i$$
for random variables $x_i$.

What is the distribution of $$\lVert\sum_i x_i M_i\rVert_1=\sum \sigma_k?$$
Here $\sigma_k$s are singular values of $\sum_i x_i M_i$.

What is the distribution of $$\frac{\lVert\sum_i x_i M_i\rVert_1}{\lVert\sum_i x_i M_i\rVert_2}?$$

What is the eigenvalue distribution (the vector of the eigenvalues) of $\sum_i x_i M_i$, if $x_i$ are independent Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$? If $x_i$ are uniform distribution in $[a_i,b_i]$?

Comment: Do you mean multiset rather than vector of eigenvalues?

Comment: I am interested in the vector of eigenvalues.

Comment: In what order do you put the eigenvalues in the vector?

Comment: If you want to map a $d\times d$ complex matrix $M$ to a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{C}^d$ that records the eigenvalues of $M$, then we should take $v=(e_1,\dots,e_d)$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th elementary symmetric function of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @Stanley Yes. Thank you very much for clarifying this point. I think I am more interested in the distribution of the sum of singular values.

Comment: If your $M_i$ are the standard basis (that is $M_{\alpha \beta}$ is the matrix all of whose entries are 0 except for the $(\alpha \beta)$ entry which equals $1$) and $x_i$ are Gaussian then your matrix is a real Ginibre one, and the joint distribution of its singular values (modulu permutation) corresponds to Wishart.  The limiting empirical measure is then the Marchenko-Pastur law, and the sum of singular values is expressible as its mean.

Comment: @zeitouni Thank you very much!!! Are another basis well studied rather than the standard basis?